# Resetting tim.perf_counter() to start from 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am trying to write a time value into a 16 bit register. The value I am writing in is the time received from time.perf_counter() which is the running time, however when I get to 65535 I want to reset the timer. Is it possible to do this or is there another way to restart the timer? The reason I cannot use datetime or seconds timing value is because I need everything to be in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just take the remainder when dividing by 65535 with the modulo operator `%`:

```py
In [114]: int(time.perf_counter()*1000) % 65535
Out[114]: 29548
```

If you also are interested to know how many times the timer has been resetted, you can use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```py
In [115]: divmod(int(time.perf_counter()*1000),65535)
Out[115]: (31, 30036)
```